# Simplify value + null check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to simplify the code that I actually have. I have problems when I want to simplify for example:

Instead of

```
(CF3.STRINGVALUE = 'Empty' OR CF3.STRINGVALUE IS NULL)
```

Maybe

```
(CF3.STRINGVALUE = 'Empty' OR IS NULL)
```

but it doesnt let me

```
jis.created, 
jis.resolutiondate,
IIF(CF3.STRINGVALUE like 'IDR-%','SI','NO') AS 'Massive',
cfo8.customvalue AS 'Solved in first go',
IIF(DATEDIFF(ss, LAG(jis.resolutiondate) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC), jis.CREATED) < 604800 AND (CF3.STRINGVALUE = 'Empty' OR CF3.STRINGVALUE IS NULL) AND (cfo8.customvalue = 'NO' OR cfo8.customvalue IS NULL) AND (ist.pname = 'Avería (FTTH)' OR ist.pname ='Avería (xDSL)') AND (LAG(ist.pname, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC) = 'Avería (FTTH)' OR LAG(ist.pname, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC) = 'Avería (xDSL)'), 'SI', 'NO') AS 'Reitero CM',
IIF(DATEDIFF(ss, LAG(jis.resolutiondate) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC), jis.CREATED) < 604800 AND cfo1.customvalue = LAG(cfo1.customvalue, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC) AND (CF3.STRINGVALUE = 'Empty' OR CF3.STRINGVALUE IS NULL) AND (cfo8.customvalue = 'NO' OR cfo8.customvalue IS NULL) AND (ist.pname = 'Avería (FTTH)' OR ist.pname ='Avería (xDSL)') AND (LAG(ist.pname, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC) = 'Avería (FTTH)' OR LAG(ist.pname, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC) = 'Avería (xDSL)'), 'SI', 'NO') AS 'Reitero MM',
cfo1.customvalue AS 'Motivo de la Averia',
LAG(cfo1.customvalue, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE, jis.issuenum ASC) AS 'Motivo anterior de la Averia'

FROM [DWH].[JIR].[jiraissue] jis
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF1 ON (CF1.issue = jis.id AND CF1.CUSTOMFIELD = 10004)
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF2 ON (CF2.issue = jis.id AND CF2.CUSTOMFIELD = 10026) /*Motivo de la Averia*/
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].customfieldoption cfo1 ON (CF2.customfield = cfo1.customfield AND CF2.stringvalue=CAST(cfo1.id AS CHAR))
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF3 ON (CF3.issue = jis.id AND CF3.CUSTOMFIELD = 10032)
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].[customfieldvalue] CF14 ON (CF14.issue = jis.id AND CF14.CUSTOMFIELD = 10906)
LEFT JOIN [DWH].[JIR].customfieldoption cfo8 ON (CF14.customfield = cfo8.customfield AND CF14.stringvalue=CAST(cfo8.id AS CHAR))
LEFT JOIN dwh.jir.issuetype ist ON ist.ID = jis.issuetype

ORDER BY CF1.STRINGVALUE ASC
```

Any help or advice is really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  *Explain* what the code is supposed to be doing.  Also, I removed the "mysql" tag, because the syntax strongly suggests SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no - there is no "better" here. You could apply ISNULL to avoid a bit of typing. Example:

```
(ISNULL(CF3.STRINGVALUE, 'Empty') = 'Empty')
```

Seems like a trivial amount of extra typing is saved to me. Internally, the engine will do the same amount of work. The world of an EAV design is not a fun place to write code.